# Streaming to/from Android using SRTP

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libjingle

I'm struggling to create an Android app that receives Audio and Video from a camera using SRTP, and at the same time, sends audio recorded from the microphone back.

The initial idea was to use FFMPEG and try to scramble something together, but haven't been able to find much useful info, everything is either too old, too advanced or too little documented.

My approach currently is trying to do the same using Libjingle, but I'm not having much luck, everything I seem to find is once again extremely hard to grasp or it uses anything other than SRTP.

---

Any tips, libraries, samples, tutorials or general guidance will be extremely appreciated.